# antecedent for "which"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> Fridges were especially useful for storing perishable substances such
>   as milk, **which** had previously been the cause of thousands of
>   deaths every year in the big cities of the world.

In the above sentence, would the antecedent of the relative pronoun **which** be "milk" or "perishable substances such as milk". I get confused whenever I try to identify the antecedents of relative pronouns with two or more NPs joined together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would there be a some kind of a rule for determining the antecedent of relative expressions?

Comment: Non-defining relatives (the kind with a comma, like your example) allow a wide range of antecedents from full noun phrases to clauses. Defining relatives by contrast allow only nominals (noun phrases excluding any determiners, but including modifiers). In the latter case, it's usually the nominal that is nearest to the relative pronoun, though there are a few minor exceptions to that. Defining relatives can exceptionally allow superlative adjectives and integrated prepositions as antecedent.

Comment: There is no possible syntactic method of determining the exact referent of *which*. As such, it's open to semantic interpretation.

Comment: I'd say that the antecedent is the clause "storing perishable substances such as milk". It was the storing that had caused thousands of deaths, not the perishable substances such as milk (which if not stored would not have caused the deaths).

Comment: It’s the perishable substances which cause the deaths. This we know. If the sentence is confusing, recast.

Answer (score -1):

*which had previously been the cause of thousands of deaths every year in the big cities of the world* is a non-restrictive relative clause:

> Non-restrictive relative clauses give us *additional information* about
>   a noun that has already been identified, but this information is not
>   essential for the sentence to make sense. Because of this,
>   non-restrictive relative clauses are set apart from the rest of the
>   sentence by commas.

The noun in question is *milk*, in this case.

**Addendum**

The phrase says "big cities of the world" and it is placed just after *milk*. It leads to believe that it is specifically talking about problems regarding the consumption of milk in big cities, like [Chicago](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4890836/) and other [US cities](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3ed0/fc457fd5ed9a5b76deb847705594a9b38a34.pdf), which were actually largely quench because of the introduction of [pasteurization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurization#process), for which refrigeration is necessary.

We can rephrase the sentence in a way that is much closer to *perishable substances* than *milk*: *Fridges were especially useful for storing perishable substances, which had previously been the cause of thousands of deaths every year in the big cities of the world, such as milk.* Hence my "leads to believe" in the previous paragraph. However, it could be that the author is not talking only about milk in that clause.

---

The Farlex Grammar Book. S.v. "Relative Clauses." Retrieved September 1 2019 from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Relative-Clauses.htm

Comment: Well, the actual antecedent is probably the gerund noun phrase _storing perishable substances such as milk_, which is the object of the preposition _for_, and which includes but is not limited to milk as the cause for all those deaths.

Comment: Did milk _really_ kill 'thousands of people'?

Comment: @John Lawler So the sentence is either wrongly constructed or nonsensical (?)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey _raw milk was associated with 25% of all disease outbreaks from food/water during the time before World War II in the U.S._ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_milk#Epideomiology). However, syntactically, people seem to disagree

Comment: OK, but did it really 'kill thousands of people', or did you make that up?

Comment: @Edwin No, I wouldn't say that. The sentence is fine, if prolix.  It's the identification of the antecedent that I was disagreeing with. Phrases and clauses are more likely than single words.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Yes.  I looked at the CDC's article, "Achievements in Public Health, 1900-1999" (https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm4840a1.htm).  It says, "During the early 20th century, contaminated food, milk, and water caused many foodborne infections, including typhoid fever, tuberculosis, botulism, and scarlet fever.... In 1900, the incidence of typhoid fever was approximately 100 per 100,000 population."  Google tells me the population in the US in 1900 was about 76 million, so yes, microbes getting into the digestive system would have been responsible for many deaths.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Oh, I forgot to say, I looked at the Amazon preview of the book, "Consider the Fork," which the quote was taken from.  The author was talking about how helpful the rise of the refrigerator in the late 19th century was.

Comment: @JohnLawler In this case, considering the phrase the antecedent renders the sentence nonsensical. Storing perishables was never the cause of thousands of deaths; the perishables themselves were. Phrases and clauses may be more likely in general, but not in this case.

Comment: @Janus I'm glad I looked up the page; I was just about to post the same query. I'd certainly rephrase (or if marking strictly, reach for the red pen).

Answer (score -1):

perishable substances such as milk

Apparently milk wasn't the only transmitter of dangerous pathogens. The CDC has an [article](http://chttps://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm4840a1.htm), "Achievements in Public Health, 1900-1999," which says, "During the early 20th century, contaminated food, milk, and water caused many foodborne infections, including typhoid fever, tuberculosis, botulism, and scarlet fever."

An [article at MilkFacts.info](http://milkfacts.info/Milk%20Processing/Heat%20Treatments%20and%20Pasteurization.htm) shows that milk was a significant problem, but not the only one: "In 1938, milk products were the source of 25% of all food and waterborne illnesses that were traced to sources."

Once we understand the ideas behind the sentence more fully, we can feel more confident, certain, in fact, that the author didn't intend *milk* to be the sole antecedent.

Comment: The phrase says "big cities of the world" and it is placed just after _milk_. It leads to believe that it is specifically talking about problems regarding the consumption on milk in big cities, like [Chicago](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4890836/) and other [US cities](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3ed0/fc457fd5ed9a5b76deb847705594a9b38a34.pdf), which were actually largely quench because of the introduction of [pasteurization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurization#process), for which refrigeration is necessary.

Comment: @Alberto It says “big cities _of the world_”, not just the US. It’s also placed just after “perishable substances such as milk” – proximity is not a usable measure when the two possibilities are equidistant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet We can safely assume that if it was happening in every major city in the US it was happening everywhere else. How many countries do you need till we can assert that? We can rephrase the sentence in a way that is much closer to _perishable substances_ and not _milk_: _Fridges were especially useful for storing perishable substances, which had previously been the cause of thousands of deaths every year in the big cities of the world, such as milk._ Hence my "leads to believe". Of course, I might be wrong.